# Web2py with paramiko for ssh functionality

Tags: python, ssh, web2py, paramiko

I have a form built via web2py that i need to use to validate and register a machine and store it into a database. The validation is not passing through. I am always getting error that "Houston there seems to be a problem with Machine name or super password". If i run the paramiko script outside the web2py environment it is working fine. Please help.

Form Details:

```
db.define_table('nsksystem',
  Field('nskmachinename', length=128, requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY(error_message='Machine Name cant be empty'), label = T('Machine Name')),
  Field('nskpassword', 'password', length=512,readable=False, label=T('Machine Password')),
  Field('confirmnskpassword', 'password', length=512,readable=False, label=T('Confirm Machine Password'))        )
```

Controller: default.py( for validating the form insertion before inserting)

```
def machinevalidate(form):
  host = form.vars.nskmachinename
  user ='superman'
  pwd = form.vars.nskpassword

  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())    
  try:
    ssh.connect(host, username=user,password=pwd)
    return True
  except Exception, e:
    form.errors.nskpassword = 'Houston there seems to be a problem with Machine name or super password'
finally:
    ssh.close()
```

Controller: default.py (for the insertion into database)

```
@auth.requires_login()
def machine():
form = SQLFORM(db.nsksystem)
if form.process(onvalidation=machinevalidate).accepted:
    response.flash = 'The machine is now registered to the user.'
elif form.errors:
    response.flash = 'Form has errors'
else:
    response.flash = 'Please register a machine to your ID'
return dict(form=form)
```

After the suggestion I removed the try/ catch and here is the traceback of error. I have wintypes.py under Lib/ctypes. But still then couldnot figure out why there is an import error.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gluon/restricted.py", line 224, in restricted
  File "C:/web2py/applications/click/controllers/default.py", line 53, in <module>
  File "gluon/globals.py", line 393, in <lambda>
  File "gluon/tools.py", line 3444, in f
  File "C:/web2py/applications/click/controllers/default.py", line 39, in machine
    if form.process(onvalidation=machinevalidate).accepted:
   File "gluon/html.py", line 2303, in process
  File "gluon/html.py", line 2240, in validate
  File "gluon/sqlhtml.py", line 1461, in accepts
  File "gluon/html.py", line 2141, in accepts
  File "gluon/html.py", line 146, in call_as_list
  File "C:/web2py/applications/click/controllers/default.py", line 33, in machinevalidate
   ssh.connect(host, username=user,password=pwd)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 307, in connect
   look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 456, in _auth
self._agent = Agent()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\agent.py", line 332, in __init__
from . import win_pageant
 File "gluon/custom_import.py", line 105, in custom_importer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\win_pageant.py", line 25, in <module>
  import ctypes.wintypes
  File "gluon/custom_import.py", line 105, in custom_importer
 ImportError: No module named wintypes
```

Comment: I would start by getting rid of that `try` / `except` and let the exception fall through so you can see what the exception actually is.

Comment: Posting the error log after removing try/catch. It gives an import error. But the wintypes module is there under ctypes in my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution...
I was using the compiled version of web2py. When i used the source code, importing of modules were not a head ache any more. Thank you Andrew Magee for giving a heads up...